# How do I update second entry in an entry?

Tags: mongodb

**Goal:**

1. If array is empty create it
2. Else add objects to it.

To find the array - I have added a boolean flag.

**Purpose:**
I am storing everyday logs in an array. One day logs for a key goes into an array as an object. For second day, i need to create another object.

**Problem:**

1. I am facing difficulties for the second entry
2. If design is not correct, please suggest - I prefer this least.

**Queries I perform**:

1. Check whether all logs are matching within an object.
2. Check whether any changes happened between two objects for a key

**Design**

```
{
    "_id" : "1|2",
    "logs" : [ 
        {
            "readerLogs" : { //I make sure that I create this first time always - handling at application side
                "a" : "b",
                "c" : "d"
            },
            "isActive" : false,
            "writerLogs" : { //has to be added to active entry
                "a" : "b",
                "c" : "d"
            },
            "dbLogs" : {//has to be added to active entry
                "a" : "b",
                "c" : "d"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Working Queries which I am using:

I run this query on reader log file for first time - as upsert cannot be used on array

```
db.getCollection('test').update({"_id": "1|2", 
    "logs":{"$elemMatch":{"isActive":true}}},
{$push:{"logs":{"readerLogs":{"a":"b", "c":"d"}, "isActive":true}}},
{upsert:true})
```

To add another logs for the same system

```
db.getCollection('test').update({"_id": "1|2", 
    "logs":{"$elemMatch":{"isActive":true}}},
{$set:{"logs.$.writerLogs":{"a":"b", "c":"d"}}})
```

To add another log on the same object

```
db.getCollection('test').update({"_id": "1|2", 
    "logs":{"$elemMatch":{"isActive":true}}},
{$set:{"logs.$.dbLogs":{"a":"b", "c":"d"}}})
```

Once all logs are updated, I perform this so that next entry will be created for next day run

```
db.test.update({"logs":{"$elemMatch":{"isActive":true}}}, 
{$set:{"logs.$.isActive":false}})
```

But unfortunately, it is not happening - on next day run, it throws `duplicate key`  error on first query - I understand the reason - Please help to resolve this.

I tried to have a date entry for each object's key as

```
"logs":[
 {
  2020-08-23 : {
  }
 }
]
```

Comment: First time for every object in logs or only for creation of logs - `readerLogs` query part?

Comment: It can be for every objects.